# How do I cast QML items to corresponding C++ Item in Qt Quick

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, qobject, qtquickcontrols

My question is best clarified by an example. I have QML with a `Text{}` item. In C++ I can get to this item and I have no problem using `qobject_cast` to turn anything into a `QQuickItem*`. But how do I turn it into the closest corresponding item so that I can call more specific methods directly like `setText()` the same way I might call `setWidth()`?  I realize I can use the generic setProperty() method but I'm after the compile time checking that casting offers.

I'm after a more general answer for finding the correspondence between QML and their C++ classes, so that I can find out how to do this for Rectangles, MenuBars etc. I can't seem to find this in the docs.  For those that prefer code examples:

```
auto text_object = app_item->findChild<QObject*>("myTextArea");
text_object->setProperty("text","New Text set from Code"); //THIS WORKS BUT...
auto text_qitem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(text_object);
text_qitem->setWidth(128);
auto text_quick_text = qobject_cast<WHATGOESHERE???*>(text_object);
text_quick_text->setText("new Text for qml item");  //I WANT TO DO THIS
```

Comment: you are assuming that there's a native c++ class for each qtquick control, could it be that is not the case..

Comment: I'm just hoping if that is the case that there exists documentation somewhere stating what correspondence does exist. For example, I can cast the 0th element of the engine.rootObjects to a QQuickWindow. But I figured that out by guessing.

Comment: @perencia: there is...

Comment: @Tod: you [can get the classname](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#className), but I am not sure how to turn the string into object cast, to be honest.

Comment: Well that gave me the idea to just use the debugger. I can see all the children of the app and the Text{} item is of type QQuickText. Unfortunately I can't find an include that will let me cast to this.

Comment: You could build a static Lut.

Comment: Can I ask you to clarify why you need such? Perhaps you should change the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: but I'm after the compile time checking that casting offers.

qobject_cast does not offer any compilation-time checking. It is all runtime and dynamic, thus this request is not plausible. The context property is fine, or you could also get the class name with [QMetaObject](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#className). Then, you could build a static LUT, but the effort may not be worth it overall...

Comment: OK, and it seems I can get the same type of safety from QMetaObject.  I'm really just interested in understanding all this better. I would still like to know what I would use to cast something to a Text{}. Really I want to know in general how to find in the documentation the correspondence between a Qt Quick class like Text and the C++ equivalent. Maybe it isn't documented because it's starting to appear though that even though I saw this technique in the docs, doing things this way is not the proper technique.

Answer (score 0):

All QML properties and methods are exposed to the meta-object system and can be called from C++ using Object::setProperty and QMetaObject::invokeMethod() respectively. invokeMethod parameters and return values passed from QML are always translated into QVariant values in C++:

```
QString msg("That's it");

auto text_object = app_item->findChild<QObject*>("myTextArea");

if (text_object)
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(text_object, "append", Q_ARG(QString, msg));
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32411771)